# case statement doesn't go to else

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering why the following query doesn't give 'N/A' when there are no rows for ENVIRON='Dev/Int'. It is returning null in the result of the query. I tried doing NVL(COUNT(*)) but that does't work either.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT G1.NAME, 
  (SELECT CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 AND ticket IS NOT NULL THEN 'Solved'
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 AND ticket IS  NULL THEN 'Done'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE ENVIRON='Dev/Int' AND G1.NAME=NAME GROUP BY ENVIRON, ticket ) "Dev/Int"
FROM TABLE1 G1 group by G1.NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't give any rows because you are filtering them all out.  The `case` is *inside* the query.  When there are no rows to process, it returns NULL.

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  The subqueries don't seem necessary:

```
SELECT G1.NAME, 
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ENVIRON = 'Dev/Int' then 1 else 0 END) > 0 AND ticket IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'Solved'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ENVIRON = 'Dev/Int' then 1 else 0 END) > 0 AND ticket IS NULL
             THEN 'Done'
             ELSE 'N/A'
        END) as "Dev/Int"
FROM TABLE1
group by G1.NAME;
```

EDIT:

Oops, the above left `ticket` out of the `sum()`.  I think the logic you want has ticket in the `sum()` condition:

```
SELECT G1.NAME, 
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ENVIRON = 'Dev/Int' AND ticket IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'Solved'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ENVIRON = 'Dev/Int' AND ticket IS NULL then 1 else 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'Done'
             ELSE 'N/A'
        END) as "Dev/Int"
FROM TABLE1
group by G1.NAME;
```

I'm surprised your original query worked at all and didn't get an error of the sort that subquery returned more than one row.

Comment: Awesome Gordon, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just noticed that this returns multiple rows for the name (e.g. multiple tickets associated with name). I need to add ticket to group by other it is complaining "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.". How can I not group by ticket ?  Thanks